# Why is the top of the wing low pressure?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, lift

I think it's because the wing has an angle of attack and the flow passage at the top of the wing is widened, so the resistance of air flow at the top of the wing is reduced. But some people don't think so. They think it's because the top of the wing has a long distance, so the velocity is fast, so the pressure is reduced. Are they right?

Comment: Coincidentally, today Fermat's Library posted a link to Andersson's "How airplanes fly" that deal with the common bad explanations and the real reason: https://fermatslibrary.com/s/how-airplanes-fly-a-physical-description-of-lift Might be the start of an answer (which clearly has to be more than a link like this).

Comment: @Anders, excellent link. Finally, somebody that gets it. Note that most professionally designed wings are fairly symmetrical. The only real reason for asymmetry is because the chord may be so long that it helps to better follow the slight downward acceleration of the air near its surface as the air moves over the wing. (Note that ideally the wing should have a very short chord, like in a sailplane. The chord is typically longer only for structural reasons.)

Comment: As my aerodynamics professor used to say if the surrounding fluid is fast enough and the angle of attack right you can also use a bam door for flying.